# How add field deadline in TRAC?

Tags: trac, deadlines

I want to add new field "**deadline**" for tickets in a [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) system . 
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at [Custom Ticket Fields](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracTicketsCustomFields).

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with a modified revision of the Trac development version 0.13dev, that has [support for true custom time fields](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/Proposals/TracTicketsCustomTimeFields). This version performs well in production for more than a year now, but still lacks some requirements like unittest to make it's way into the next stable release of Trac. Until this is at least in 'trunk' you'll have to take [a special revision](http://trac.edgewall.org/changeset/dbf31705fb2cae3e9ab44587abb96ec1dcd587f5/rblank) from the repository, patch Trac code on your own or use the [DateFieldPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/DateFieldPlugin).

BTW, there is [CustomFieldAdminPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/CustomFieldAdminPlugin) to help you prepare properly formatted entries for [ticket-custom] section of your trac.ini .